# Core Data - Adding Multiple Child Entities To An Array

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to build a to-do list app.

So far I have an entity for storing categories. Within the category entity, it has 3 relationships. One to a task entity, one to an event entity and one to a reminder entity.

In my app, I would like to be able to go into a category and see a `tableView` filled with tasks, reminders, and events.

So far, my `tableView` works with just have one child entity. This so done through the following code:

```
func loadEvents(with request: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentCategory.name MATCHES %@", selectedCategory!.name!)
    request.predicate = predicate

    do {
        itemsArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    print(itemsArray)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem happens when I try to add all 3 child types to the same array. Nothing shows up in the table view. (I have support for multiple cell types in my table view too.)

I have tried this code:

```
func loadItems(with request: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()) {
    itemsArray = []

    let taskRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentCategory.name MATCHES %@", selectedCategory!.name!)
    taskRequest.predicate = predicate

    let eventRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()
    eventRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        itemsArray.append(try context.fetch(taskRequest))
        itemsArray.append(try context.fetch(eventRequest))
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    print(itemsArray)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But my table view just appears empty. My array is also an array of `Any`.

Any help on how to add the different child entities to the same array would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Don't use `Any`. `Any` is the worst type. Look always for a common denominator. `itemsArray` is at least `[NSManagedObject]`.

Comment: you should define a Protocol `item` and make your `event` and `task` conforms to it, this protocol could define a func that returns what you need to show in your tableview, then you could append event and task to an array `var itemsArray = [item]()`